# New user home directory not recognized / accepted upon login

Tags: login, home-directory, user-management

I can't log in to my home directory after user creation:
I reinstalled my system fresh (Ubuntu 14.04.3). Created an admin user. Added my main user with `adduser me`. I get feedback along the lines:

> Home directory created, copying files from /etc/skel

The directory is listed in `/etc/passwd`
and it is owned by `me`, with 755 permissions.
also, `usermod -d /home/me me` gives: no changes

Still, the terminal logs `me` in with: `No directory, logging in with HOME=/`
and the graphical login throws me back to the login screen.

Anything else I can try?

Comment: Silly question, but does `/home/me` actually exists? You never stated this explicitly. Have you checked?

Comment: well yes, it is owned by me with 755 permissions. it exists.

Comment: `$HOME` might be being set wrongly, try `export HOME=/home/me`, `su me` and see if you get the same error

Comment: That was indeed set wrong: `echo $HOME: /`. I set it as you said, still didnt fix it, or rather I couldn't permanently change it when logged in as `me`, it would jump back after re-log on. only then I realized the parent directory `/home` was owned by the first created admin user for some reason, permissions 700. Setting those to 755 now I can log in successfully. Thanks.

Comment: Glad that you solved, tough I don't know how that could have happened. However `/home` should be owned by root:root, you might want to fix that as well

Comment: Ya I fixed that too. Should I repost the solution as an answer to accept it or leave it as it is? Or do you care to, you brought me to the answer after all.

Comment: Nah, I suggested something else, the problem was indeed `/home`'s permissions. Yes I think it would be better, that way the fact that the question is solved and the solution itself would both stick out more. Drop me a comment once done for a quick +10 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out somehow the `/home` directory was owned by the first created admin user for some reason, with permissions `700`. Changing the owner back to root:root and setting permissions to `755`, now I can log in successfully with user `me`.

Comment: right, that slipped my mind, I updated the answer, thanks.